# Looking for the interesting usages of linearity of expectation

Tags: probability, soft-question, random-variables, expected-value

I am going to give a presentation about the basics of probability and for that, I would like to include some interesting (or even better mind-blowing) examples of how linearity of expectation can help solve problems. I have two examples in mind for now, but before proceeding, I thought it was good to ask for other ideas.

My examples are:

1. Expected value of the number of fixed points in a random permutation.

> You can write $X = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n$ , and then $EX = n\times EX_1 = 1$

2. Solving Buffon's needle by bending it. (AKA [Buffon's noodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_noodle))

If you have any, please share them with me.

Comment: This is very well-documented already: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985462/striking-applications-of-linearity-of-expectation#:~:text=Linearity%20of%20expectation%20is%20a,otherwise%20make%20any%20calculation%20daunting.